# JS feature detection to detect the usage of -webkit-calc over calc

Tags: javascript, css, feature-detection

So I'm quite aware that in general, one should use feature detection in JS vs. browser detection. A good example of this being pushed is `jQuery 1.9`'s drop of `$.browser`.

In addition, in every article I read, it says to never use browser detection.

But I have a condition where I need to dynamically calculate the `#` of `"slots"` available in a JS layout, and it's being done through `calc(100%/{0})`, where `{0}` is the `#` of slots available.

Of course, in iPad, the `.css("height", "calc(100%/3)")` will fail, as it must be prefixed with `-webkit-`.

So, can anyone tell me how exactly I should use feature detection (instead of the old `$.browser.webkit`) to detect that it requires this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a dummy element, insert it in the document, use `.cssText.height = 'calc(100px - 50px);'`, and check if the element has the expected height. Repeat this for every vendor-prefix.

Side note: For this kind of questions, you should look in the source code of Modernizr. Others have usually contributed such feature detection scripts, such as [`calc.js`](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/css/calc.js).

---

Modernizr detects whether the feature is present, it doesn't tell which prefix has to be used. The code below shows how to get the correct prefix:

```
var calc = (function(){
    var dummy = document.createElement('div');
    var props = ['calc', '-webkit-calc', '-moz-calc', '-o-calc'];
    for (var i=0; i<props.length; ++i) {
        var prop = props[i];
        dummy.style.cssText = 'width:' + prop + '(1px);';
        if (dummy.style.length)
            return prop;
    }
})();

// Usage example:
$('selector').css('height', calc + '(100% / 3)');
```

(I did not add the `-ms-` prefix, because IE started supporting it without the prefix - see http://caniuse.com/calc.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is clear. I can't say that this is 'better' than simple browser detection in terms of complexity, but I understand the argument against using something as informal and fickle as agent string